geo coords in plotly scatterplot, not scatter_geo / 'owning the math'
I am experimenting with simple plotly scatterplot animations involving GIS data. I want to be able to plot coordinates in various localized EPSGs with scatter(), not scatter_geo(). Tile services and other geo goodies are less important here than being able to iterate with different applications of randomness and visual density in the animations.
gdal seems worth a time investment but I am not sure it's necessary for this immediate purpose. I see https://pypi.org/project/pyepsg/ may also help, but a concurrent goal is to develop a better casual/working understanding of geodesy and 'own the math' in the code to some reasonable extent.
I am looking for: key terms and equations I need to get a handle on transformations in order to get this up and running. It is possible that working through the implementation of scatter_geo() would be the best path, and I likely will do this, but I want more of a quickstart at the moment. Happy for specific or general breadcrumbs.
scatterplot() will show geographic data but distortions are evident on square (fig.layout.xaxis == fig.layout.yaxis -> >>> True) plots. I need a better purchase on the math.
